# Equivalence class of a number on a relation?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

> Lets say there is an equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if and only if $x-y$ is an integer. Find the equivalence class of the number $\frac13$.

I came up with $\left[\frac13\right]=\left\{\frac13\right\}$ but I'm not sure if its right. Any tips?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the definition makes no sense; equivalence relations are defined on pairs of numbers, not single numbers!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel In the post, the relation is already defined in terms of pairs of numbers. So I don't get your vote to close the question. Also it asks for the equivalence class of a single number, always a valid question.

Comment: @coffeemath I meant "find the equivalence class of the _number_ $\frac13$"...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Still seems OK to talk about an *equivalence class* of a (single) number.

Comment: @coffeemath $x$, $y$ or both?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I'd assume it does not need reference to $x$ or $y$ to define the equivalence class of a single element in the field of the relation $R.$ It would just be $[a]=\{b:bRa\}$ so here the "extra variable" $b$ could be denoted by any letter, and in this problem $a=1/3.$

Comment: An equivalence relation must be defined on a set. What set is $\sim$ defined on?

Answer (score 0):

Your $x$ is fixed and equal to $1/3$.

Let $x-y=k\in Z$ , then $y=x-k=\frac{1}{3}-k$ is the equivalence class you're looking for. $1/3$ is just one element of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $S=\{(x,y)\mid x-y\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Suppose that $(1/3,y)\in S$, then $1/3-y=n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y=1/3-n$. Moreover, if $y=1/3-n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $(1/3,y)\in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $(1/3,y)\in S$ if and only if $y=1/3-n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.